# Upgrading Rancher's Let's encrypt for ACMEv2 support

Tags: docker, lets-encrypt, rancher

I'am using [Let's encrypt community for rancher][1] but since ACMEv1 is deprecated, it doesn't work anymore, i have this classic message

```
30/01/2020 16:29:04time="2020-01-30T15:29:04Z" level=fatal msg="LetsEncrypt client: Failed to register account: acme: Error 403 - urn:acme:error:unauthorized - Account creation on ACMEv1 is disabled. Please upgrade your ACME client to a version that supports ACMEv2 / RFC 8555. See https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/end-of-life-plan-for-acmev1/88430 for details."
```

I saw there's is updated image to address this issues : https://github.com/janeczku/rancher-letsencrypt/issues/110 and in particular :

https://hub.docker.com/r/vxcontrol/rancher-letsencrypt/ or better https://github.com/TrueCarry/rancher-letsencrypt/tree/acme-v2

But since i am new at Rancher, i can figure how to use this image instead the old one ?

Can someone help me to understand how it works ?

I am using Rancher 1.6.29

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I feel so dumb ... i just did an upgrade of the container, giving the uadevops/rancher-letsencrypt image, and worked flawless